# Allow non-authenticated users to write into firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a contact form and understood that a quick way to do it would be to write the data into the firestore and then use the [trigger e-mail](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) extension to fire the email.

I've set up the contact form page already and are sending the fields after input validation to the firestore:

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("users").add({
    name: getInputVal('name'),
    email: getInputVal('email'),
    phone: getInputVal('phone'),
    message: getInputVal('message')
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

I'm using Firestore only for messages (and everything else is kept in the real-time database, where i've managed to create sufficient security rules). Looks like something is wrong with my permissions?

What i'd like to set-up:

1. Allow non-authenticated users to write into Firestore `messages` collection
2. Allow only admin users to read/delete messages
3. Set up a validation on db level that the length of any fields wouldn't exceed 200 characters and would only be with a type of String

I tried following the logic from real time database, and have the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /messages/{message}{
        allow write: if true
        allow read: if "request.auth.uid === 'my_user_id'"
    }
}
}
```

However, I end up catching an error `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` every time I try to run the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /users/{user}{
         allow create: if true;
         allow read, delete: if request.auth.uid === 'my_user_id';
       }
   }
}
```

---

Note that you should not put quotes around `request.auth.uid == 'my_user_id';`

Note also that you should use more [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=0#granular_operations), i.e. `create` and `delete`.

---

For the requirement "the length of any fields wouldn't exceed 200 characters and would only be with a type of String" you need, for each field, to do:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.field1.size() < 200 && request.resource.data.field2.size() < 200;
```

Comment: Looks like rules don't like `===` and had to replace it with `==`. However, i'm still receiving the same output as initially.

Comment: What is the request you try to execute?

Comment: Not sure on your exact question - I catch the error in the function shown above, on the network tab I can see a POST towards: `https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel`
Edit: Added the `let db = firebase.firestore();` to the code example above.

Comment: Oh, wow. I had a `users` defined as a collection instead of `messages` in code. Swapped that, and got a result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, the request is the code to write to the DB. It is at the top of the question.... I think I've found the problem: you write to the `users` collection but your rule is for the `messages` collection. I've adapted it.

Comment: Our comments crossed, but you were faster than me to detect it :-) Please upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem.